# How to get list of users not in a particular group - unix aix

Tags: unix, aix

I am trying to retrieve the list of users who are not present in a particular group.

We are trying to validate an application with the user credentials through unix AIX server and the user should be present in a particular group. For now, we need to get the list of users who are not in the group (*for our testing with various test scenarios*).

I tried the below command to list users in a group.

"**lsgroup -a users groupname**"

Please help me how to use NOT ! operator for the above command or let me know if there is any other way to get users not in a group.

--Suriya

Comment: Do you have a list of users that you want to check against or are you using the complete list of userids on the server as your input?

Comment: Hi acer123, i do not have list of users of a group. If i try to list down all users, the result is too big to compare.

Comment: Did my answer below resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to string together a couple of commands.   The following example will list all users that are not in a specific group.

```
lsuser -a groups ALL | grep -v $GROUP |awk '{print $1}'|sort
```

Comment: It is not working. It is listing me the usage patterns for grep command as "usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] -e pattern_list..."

Comment: i want users who are all not in group 'XYZ'. Following your command, i gave the command as 

lsuser -a groups ALL | grep -v $XYZ |awk '{print $1}'|sort

please let me know if i gave the command in correct way

Comment: please give me the output of the following command:  which grep

Comment: "/usr/bin/grep" this was the output.
is there any other options to list down the users? Please help

Comment: The $GROUP is a variable. You don't type that in. You type in what the actual group is that you are interested in.   So, an example would be:    lsuser -a groups ALL | grep -v staff | awk '{print $1}' | sort

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you ... easy way:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep groupID GID
```

You can filter using `grep` with specific group GID. 
For example you can root users using root group ID:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep 0
```

or if you want to list all the users with their group name you can use this

```
awk -F':' 'NR==FNR{ a[$3]=$1; next }{ print $1", "a[$4] }' /etc/group /etc/passwd
```